# How to create data frame by extracting strings before and after a special character in R using REGEX

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a vector of strings (>100K elements) called **VEC** which I would like to extract data from to form a data frame; sample elements are given below

```
VEC[1]

"today's performance: SW= 33.9; west =13.85 East=70.09 and the north central =125.823, S.S. = 41.5"

VEC[2]

"sent as received South= 28.76  while the West =44.55, SouthEast=64.32;  north-east =130;  south west = 38.86"

...
```

I want the output as:

[image: Data output]

The column names need not be as I have specified but should be homogeneous in order to properly define the variables.

I have used the below to match the numbers; I need help to map them to the right column with the appropriate heading.

```
m <- gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*", VEC, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(VEC, m)
```

Comment: is there always an = sign before each digit?

Comment: Are these 2 strings representative of your whole character vector? What are the context for each column value? You may extract each field value using something like [`sw <- sub(".*\\b(?:SW|south\\s*west)\\s*=\\s*(\\d[.0-9]*).*", "\\1", VEC, ignore.case=TRUE)`](https://regex101.com/r/f11eVj/1), and then create your df.

Comment: @ jasbner, there may not necessarily be an = before each digit

Comment: @ Wictor Stribizew, the fields are cardinal points and you may choose to represent them whichever way you like. How so you suggest the observations will be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know all the alternate spellings, e.g., SW vs south west? To me this seems very important as the locations are not in order. If so maybe you could do something like this:

```
pat <- "SW|south west" #alternate spellings
i <- regmatches(VEC,regexec(pat,VEC)) # find them per string
i[lengths(i) == 0] <- NA_character_ # convert zeros to nas
i <- unlist(i)
f <- function(x) gsub(paste0(".*?(?<=",i[x],")\\D+(\\d+\\.?\\d*).*"),"\\1",VEC[x],perl = T) # some regex function to extract numbers after string occurence
SW <- sapply(seq_along(VEC),f) # extract

> SW
[1] "33.9"  "38.86"
```

Repeat for each column

Probably need to tweak function to accommodate for nas, perhaps wrap in an `ifelse()`

Comment: You do not need lookbehinds here, and TRE regex flavor can cope with extracting the values. `i[x]`  can be part of the consuming pattern as it won't be used in the end..